# MultipartRequest with swagger_dart_code_generator

Tags: flutter, dart, swagger, openapi, chopper

I am using [swagger_dart_code_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/swagger_dart_code_generator) for my Flutter app to generate code based on an **openapi.json**.

It does its job for **application/json** requests, however it does not work with **multipart/form-data**.

I am sure that the api works, I tried it from the swagger web ui.

In case it helps, here are the relevant parts of the openapi.json:

```json
"post": {
    "operationId": "ImageListApiView_post_images_post",
    "requestBody": {
        "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ImageMetaForm"
                }
            }
        },
        "required": true
    },
    /* ... */
},
```

```json
"ImageMetaForm": {
    "properties": {
        "file": {
            "description": "The image to upload.",
            "format": "binary",
            "title": "File",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "file"
    ],
    "title": "ImageMetaForm",
    "type": "object"
},
```

Here is the generated code:

```dart
@override
Future<Response<ResponseImageMetaTDO>> _apiV1ImagesPost(
    {required ImageMetaForm body}) {
  final Uri $url = Uri.parse('/api/v1/images');
  final List<PartValue> $parts = <PartValue>[
    PartValue<ImageMetaForm>(
      'body',
      body,
    )
  ];
  final Request $request = Request(
    'POST',
    $url,
    client.baseUrl,
    parts: $parts,
    multipart: true,
  );
  return client.send<ResponseImageMetaTDO, ResponseImageMetaTDO>($request);
}
```

And here is the body of the outgoing request:

```
--dart-http-boundary-AJQBeUhjoUmCi.dny6r+q.hDb4gsBJeLma6Abmbpwx+0uiiNv4l
content-disposition: form-data; name="body"

{"file":"/home/melidon/Pictures/IMG_20230816_192752.jpg" }
--dart-http-boundary-AJQBeUhjoUmCi.dny6r+q.hDb4gsBJeLma6Abmbpwx+0uiiNv4l--
```

Any help is appreciated.